# Bootstrap date picker is months out

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im using Bootstrap datepicker and loading the associated textbox with a date say, today (where ever you are). But when I click the input, the picker itself is several months in the future and I don't know why?

[image]

```
<legend>Schedule</legend>
<div class="editor-label">
    <label for="ClosingDate">Closing Date</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="16/11/2013" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
        <input class="span2 datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Closing Date must be a date." data-val-required="Closing date for post is required" id="ClosingDate" name="ClosingDate" readonly="readonly" size="18" type="text" value="18/11/2013 9:46:13 p.m." />
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ClosingDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialising the format of the datepicker will help you here.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

Obligatory [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hannigan/ck57Y/)

Comment: Ok thanks, I've also now got it working by putting data_date_format="dd-mm-yyyy" as an attribute on the INPUT field which i guess is the same thing. Previously as per my posted code and the documentation URL i had it on the containing DIV. So the docs at http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ under MarkUp section put the data-date-format attr on the containing div. I'm not sure if this is an error in the docs but it clearly didn't work for me.